# Running bash script from IIS6

Tags: bash, asp-classic, iis-6

Running IIS6 on Windows 2003.  I'm trying to set up a simple ASP page which runs a bash script:

```
dim wshShell
set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

dim command
command = "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin\bash.exe /cygdrive/c/inetpub/wwwroot/test.sh"

wshShell.Run(command)
set wshShell = nothing
```

I've configured IIS6 to use the account IUSR_SERVERNAME as the identity for the default application pool, and confirmed that the script executes when I run it from the command line using

```
runas /usr:IUSR_SERVERNAME [command]
```

If I set the command to be notepad.exe, IIS6 launches it (with no window, of course, but I can see it in Task Manager, and the user name is set to IUSR_SERVERNAME).

Is there something I'm overlooking that I need to configure?  I've got a similar script running on Windows 7 / IIS7, and it wasn't difficult to get running.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: switched to the lightweight Mongoose web server (using a Tcl CGI script instead of ASP).  For our purposes -- running a simple demo -- this works fine, and it was much less painful to get it up and running.